# How to disable "constant folding" in java compilation with javac?

Tags: java, javac

I have the following Java code:

```java
public class App{
  public int sum(){
    return (1 + 2) + (3 + 4);
  }
}
```

After compiling it using `javac App.java` and inspecting the bytecode with `javap -v App`, I noticed that the method `sum` is optimized:

```
0: bipush        10
2: ireturn
```

It seems that javac performed [constant folding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_folding). Is there a way to disable this behavior by default? I'm aiming to obtain verbose bytecode, resembling the following:

```
iconst_1
iconst_2
iadd
iconst_3
iconst_4
iadd
iadd
ireturn
```

Any insights or suggestions on how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think that if you write verbose [source] code then you will get verbose bytecode, Maybe change your code to: `int sum1 = 1 + 2; int sum2 = 3 + 4; int sum = sum1 + sum2; return sum;`

Comment: @Abra: at least `sum1` and `sum2` will not have additions in them but will be folded to the result.

Comment: You can't disable it.  Compile time evaluation of compile-time *constant expressions* is required by the JLS.  (In effect, if not literally)

Comment: @StephenC actually, the specific behavior of the question is not mandated, as either compiled form has exactly the same behavior. But compilers will treat all constant expressions the same, regardless of the context, as that simplifies the implementation.